# How to select Solution file of a particular project to build in YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have two projects lets say A and B under one repository in azure Dev-ops. Each project has its own solution file.

The pipeline have tasks to build the solution and then upload the packages to the feed.

I want to select the solution file for project A if changes in pull requests are targeted for project A.

As of now i have created in a variable with default value and allowing user to override the variable name while triggering pipeline manually. PFB

[image]

> But how to achieve same behavior to auto trigger the pipelines from
> Pull Request. Is there any way to supply solution(.sln) name to
> pipeline from pull request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to implement that scenario within a single pipeline. Use two pipelines. Use different `path` filters to ensure the pipeline only triggers when appropriate paths change.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that will trigger both the pipelines no matter change is in which project causing uploading nuget feed unnecessarily

Comment: Use different `path` filters to ensure the pipeline only triggers when appropriate paths change.